# 5 bosses in a meeting room - Zebra puzzle variation

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play it online here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/meeting-room/

|  | Boss #1 | Boss #2 | Boss #3 | Boss #4 | Boss #5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tie |  |  |  |  |  |
| Name |  |  |  |  |  |
| Department |  |  |  |  |  |
| Salary |  |  |  |  |  |
| Vacations |  |  |  |  |  |
| Age |  |  |  |  |  |

Five bosses (boss #1 at the first position on the far left to #5 at the fifth position on the far right), each one from an specific department, are in the meeting room. How much each boss earn per month? Where do they go on vacations?

- ties: black, blue, green, red, yellow
- names: Adam, Julian, Nathan, Michael, Thomas
- departments: HR, IT, marketing, R&D, sales
- salaries: 2k, 3k, 4k, 5k, 6k
- vacations: January, March, June, August, December
- ages: 34, 40, 46, 51, 55

Clues:

1. Julian is at the fifth position.
2. The boss with the Red tie is going on vacation on June.
3. The man wearing the Black tie is somewhere between who earns \$3,000 and Adam, in that order.
4. The 51 years old boss makes \$2,000 monthly.
5. Michael is at the first position.
6. The boss who is going on vacation on March is in one of the ends.
7. Adam sitting is next to who earns \$4,000 each month.
8. In the fourth position is the boss who is going on vacation on August.
9. The man wearing the Black tie earns \$4,000 monthly.
10. In one of the ends is the boss who makes \$5,000 monthly.
11. The 46 years old boss is somewhere to the left of the boss who works at HR department.
12. The man from HR department is somewhere between who is 40 years old and Thomas, in that order.
13. Nathan is going on vacation on December.
14. The Sales department's boss is exactly to the right of the 46 years old boss.
15. The boss wearing the Red tie is somewhere to the left of the boss wearing the Yellow tie.
16. In the first position is the boss of R&D department.
17. The oldest boss is wearing Blue tie.
18. The man wearing the Yellow tie is in one of the ends.
19. The youngest boss is at the fifth position.
20. The boss of the Marketing department is 51 years old.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Deductions

1. Clues 1 and 19 tell us that

   > **Julian** is **34** and in the **5th** position.

   Also, by clues 15 and 18, he must be wearing

   > a **yellow** tie.
2. Clues 5 and 16 tell us that

   > **Michael** is the boss of **R&D** and in the **1st** position.
3. Clues 11 and 12 tell us that

   > the 40-year-old and 46-year-old bosses are both to the left of the HR boss, who in turn is to the left of Thomas. So Thomas must be in the 4th or 5th positions.

   But we know Michael is in the 5th, so (also using clues 8 and 14):

   - > **Thomas** is in the **4th** position and going on holiday in **August**;
   - > the **HR** boss is in the **3rd** position;
   - > the **Sales** boss is **40** and in the **2nd** position;
   - > the **46**-year-old boss is in the **1st** position.
4. Clue 20 tells us the Marketing boss isn't at the 5th position, so by elimination of departments and ages, and using also clues 4 and 17:

   - > the **Marketing** boss is **51**, makes **\$2000** monthly, and is at the **4th** position;
   - > the **IT** boss is at the **5th** position;
   - > the **55**-year-old boss is wearing a **blue** tie and is in the **3rd** position.
5. Clue 3 tells us the man with the black tie isn't at the end and is to the left of Adam, so by elimination of names and using also clues 9 and 13:

   - > **Adam** is in the **3rd** position;
   - > **Nathan** has a **black** tie, earns **\$4000** monthly, goes on holiday in **December**, and is in the **2nd** position;
   - > the boss who earns **\$3000** monthly is in the **1st** position.
6. Now the boss with the red tie must be in the 1st or 4th positions, and clue 2 tells us which:

   - > the boss with the **red** tie goes on holiday in **June** and is in the **1st** position;
   - > the boss with the **green** tie is in the **4th** position.
7. Finally, by clues 6 and 10 and then elimination:

   - > the boss in the **5th** position makes **\$5000** monthly and goes on holiday in **March**;
   - > the boss in the **3rd** position makes **\$6000** monthly and goes on holiday in **January**.

### Final solution

> [image]